# Eclipse & Python: 100% CPU load due to PythonHome reindexing

Tags: python, eclipse, cpu, pydev

I am currently switching from Eclipse Java Development more and more Python scripting using PyDev. Almost all the time there is a Eclipse backgropund thread called "reindexing PythonHome..." which loads my CPU for almost 100%. Unusable to coding in there anymore :/

Do you have any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help!

John

Comment: What operating system and versions of Eclipse / Python?  This shouldn't happen more than once per Eclipse session and shouldn't take very long.

Comment: Hey there,

Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
Eclipse Platform 3.7.1r37
PyDev 2.2.4
Python 2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable 'Build Automatically' and 'Refresh Automatically' under

   Preferences->General->Workspace
2. Disable 'Code Analysis' entirely, or configure it to only run on save under

   Preferences->PyDev->Editor->Code Analysis

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce that here (and haven't seen it happening here).

Is it possible for you to provide a thread dump of what's running when that happens? ( there are some details on how to get it at: http://pydev.org/faq.html#how_do_i_report_a_bug )